# When I POST to MongoDB, only _id is saved and

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Just to preface this question, I know there are a few question here with similar issues, I've looked through them all but I can't seem to get this to work. Also, I just started learning Mongoose today so this might be a simpleton question.

I have created a mongoose schema called task and in my express file I have a post method that creates a new document. However, when I run this post on Postman, the only thing I get back is the _id and _v and no other data is saved. I've tried changing up the Schema to see if it's how I have it saved, I also tried changing my post methods to other recommendations, but it doesn't seem to work.

Mongoose Schema (./models/Tasks.js)

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  description: { type: String },
});

const Tasks = mongoose.model("Tasks", taskSchema);

module.exports = Tasks;
```

Express File

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Tasks = require("./models/Tasks");

//App Config
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8001;
const connection_url = "MONGODB_URL"; //removed actual url

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

//Middleware

//DB Config
mongoose.connect(connection_url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

//API Endpoints
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.status(200).send("Hello Server Side!"));


app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const item = req.body;

  Tasks.create(item, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.status(201).send(data);
    }
  });
});


// Listener
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`));
```

This is the only results that I get

```
{
   "_id": "60328211204512124a35afb2",
   "__v": 0
}
```

And this is what I POST through Postman

```
{
"name": "What's happening",
"description": "Hope this works"
}
```

**EDIT:** I was a newbie and had postman set to type text and it's working now after setting it to type JSON.

Comment: Can you put `console.log(item)` right after `const item = req.body;` and show you see?

Comment: @codemonkey {} this is the only thing that shows up in the terminal

Comment: Well, there is your answer then. You need to figure that part out. Your mongodb integration works fine. This is an express issue at this point.

Comment: I have express v4.17.1 and I just installed body-parser and added `const bodyParser = require("body-parser");` and `app.use(bodyParser.json());` and `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` but still running into `item` being blank

Comment: @codemonkey I also read latest versions of express don't require body-parser so could be why it's returning the same issue.

Comment: This is all you need for body parser in your version: `app.use(express.json());` which you do have already. My next step would be making sure you're posting the data correctly via postman.

Comment: I am a simpleton. The format was correct, I just had the raw body type as text and not JSON. once I switched it over, it posted correctly. :) I appreciate your help!

Comment: if you are testing through `Postman` make sure your raw body type is of `JSON` instead of text. You can find it at the end as a drop-down selection.

EDIT:
Good to know, I deleted the previous comment and added more explanation in the current one. That issue is really annoying sometimes.

Comment: @HamzaAnis this was the issue! I am 100% grateful for your recommendation. I can't believe I spent hours trying to find a solution when it was a simple settings mistake. I thank you! :)

Comment: No worries, my pleasure.